# Trouble connecting react-native with redux

Tags: react-native, redux

I am trying to create a counter with react-native and redux, but i'm getting the error `Expected a component class, got [object Object]`.

This is my `index.android.js`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

import Root from './src/containers/Root';
import configureStore from './configureStore';

export default class CounterReactNativeRedux extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<Root store={configureStore()} />)
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('CounterReactNativeRedux', () => CounterReactNativeRedux);
```

My code can be found [here](https://github.com/diegovillacis10/CounterReactNativeRedux).

Found answers about this saying that it might be because of the class name not being capitalize but this is not the case.

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look inside of your `Counter.js`. You have used `div` tags there which do not exist in React Native.

So import `View` tag from React Native and use that.

```
import {View} from 'react-native'

const Counter = ({ value }) => (
  <View>{value}</View>
);
```

Comment: That was exactly my problem, thank you very much @Henrik